# What launch vehicle will be used for Exomars rover Rosalind Franklin?

Tags: mars, rockets, rovers, exomars

I know that for TGO/Schiaparelli, Proton was used, but I don't know what will be for Rosalind Franklin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A Proton rocket will be used to launch the mission, which will arrive
>   to Mars after a nine-month journey.

The [Proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_(rocket_family)) rocket is from [Roscosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roscosmos).

From this ESA [page](http://exploration.esa.int/mars/48088-mission-overview/)